# Is it possible to remove an uploaded package?

Tags: package

I'm wondering if anyone knows if this is possible and how to do it.  I've done some research but haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you have created a new version of the package, e.g. version 1.5 which you now want to delete so that version 1.4 is the latest version?

Comment: Hi.  I did create a package, uploaded it (it asked me to provide a version number) but I would like to reverse the upload action. Honestly I wasn't clear of the concept of package uploads.  Not sure if it's possible.  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you would have to "reverse" the upload.  I think you have two options: (1) revert the code/configuration in the source org to the code you want and upload again, or (2) migrate code/config to a new org and upload from there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, to revert the upload -- to remove the uploaded package.  Thanks for taking time to reply back.  As I said, I wasn't actually clear on the concept of uploading a package.  I'm basically new to SF development.  I'm sure we don't want the package to be uploaded for now.  It will, but in future.  Thanks.